# More gentle way to say "you can go"

Tags: synonyms

If  some body asks me "Are you coming to had coffee?"

I usually reply. `No! You can go`

I think using 'can' verb is not correct and seems to be harsh? How can i reply for them in gentle manner.

Comment: The question is not about the English language.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> "Sorry I can not come with you now.Will do it another time soon"

Answer (score 0):

'No, please carry on' is the usual way of replying to such a question 'are you coming to have some coffee?', if we are not willing/able to join the person.

Comment: Right. I forget that word